# Does the Gmail tabbed inbox in any way affect what I see in a third-party email client?

Tags: gmail

I access my (multiple) Gmail accounts almost entirely through the Mailbox app (on my iOS devices) and through Sparrow (on my Mac).

As such, I didn't get the "welcome to the tabbed inbox" message in Gmail until today, when I happened to login via the web client to do a more complex search.

So, here's my question:

**Do the tabbed inboxes do anything that's visible/accessible in an email client (adding labels, etc.), or are they basically just a custom view in the webapp that's based on attributes that are hidden from the end user?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no. The only place that I've seen a change is the Gmail app on Android doesn't send notification when non-primary emails are received (which I actually like).